# Android: How to set horizontal scroll view image margins programmatically

Tags: java, android, horizontalscrollview

I am creating a `HorizontalScrollView` in xml and inserting the images programmatically, but I am having trouble with margins. How do I set the horizontal **margins** for images in the `HorizontalScrollView`? Below is my code:

**xml:**

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/innerLay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <!--Image Views here -->

            </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**java:**

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
scrollLinearLayout.addView(imageView);
//set height and other image properties.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to set runtime margin to view

```
public static void setMargins (View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (v.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        v.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. For the View v, I should use the ImageView correct?